# Could you enable review queue one second earlier?

Tags: bug, review

### Steps to reproduce:

Reach a daily limit of some [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) and go there precisely at 00:00 UTC and check the text written at that queue. You will see a text like for instance:

> Thank you for reviewing 20 first posts today; come back **just now** to
>   continue reviewing.

Err, but I'm here **just now**, so when should I come ?

[image]

### Question:

Could you enable review queues one second earlier ?

Comment: Meh. Who cares? Refresh once and the problem is gone.

Comment: Enabling them one second earlier would just cause the "Just Now" message to display at 11:59:59, without making it any less silly.

Comment: I'm actually in favor of this. I suggested something similar a while back (for all such actions), but I'm too lazy to look for it right now.

Comment: ... or just replace "just now" with "in one second" / "in a few seconds" (seems like a simpler fix) (or, even simpler, just *pretend* it says that).

Comment: @Duke, the "just now" is also used for when there is activity on a post. If they did do that, they would have to be sure that it didn't end up saying a post was *"edited in a few seconds"* or something of the sort.

Comment: @jmac Yeah, I guess it will have to selectively be applied (though I'm rather in favour of the "pretend" approach), but it seems safer and easier than allowing you to review a few seconds earlier, which, I imagine, could have far-reaching consequences (but the devs will have to comment on that).